# Как правильно вызвать функцию inline кнопкой в телеграм боте?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, sqlite3

Продолжаю осваивать разработку телеграм ботов на python с использованием библиотеки telebot. Написал функцию проверки платежа и внесения изменений в БД. Эта функция прекрасно работает при вызове ее клавиатурой, но отказывается выполняться при вызове inline кнопкой. При нажатии на соответствующую кнопку просто ничего не происходит, код не крашится при этом. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я упускаю?

```
def ammount(message): #данная функция вызывается обычной клавиатурой
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Type in an amount')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_summa)

def get_summa(message):
    summa = message.text
    rand_code = randint(100000, 999999)
    uid = message.from_user.id
    uname = '@' + message.from_user.username
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO payment (user_id, username, summ, code, status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', (uid, uname, summa, rand_code, 'pending'))
    conn.commit()
    quickpay = Quickpay(
        receiver="wallet_ID", #тут указываю соответствующий номер
        quickpay_form="shop",
        targets="Пополнение баланса",
        paymentType="SB",
        sum=summa,
        label=rand_code
    )
    payurl = quickpay.base_url
    paymenu = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    b1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Pay', url=payurl)
    b2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Check payment', callback_data='check_payment')
    paymenu.add(b1, b2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Here is your payment url', reply_markup=paymenu)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c: True)
def inline(c):
    if c.data == 'check_payment':
        uid = c.message.from_user.id
        cursor.execute('SELECT code FROM payment WHERE user_id = ? AND status = ?', (uid, 'pending'))
        massive = cursor.fetchall()
        for i in range(len(massive)):
            check_code = massive[i][0]
            token = YTOKEN
            client = Client(token)
            history = client.operation_history(label=check_code)
            for operation in history.operations:
                summ = round(operation.amount)
                if operation.status == 'success':
                    cursor.execute('UPDATE payment SET status = ? WHERE code = ?', ('complete', check_code))
                    conn.commit()
                    cursor.execute('UPDATE bal SET balance = balance + ? WHERE user_id = ?', (summ, uid))
                    conn.commit()
                    bot.send_message(c.message.chat.id, 'SUCCESS')
```

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, показать, как вы создаёте саму клавиатуру с этой кнопкой?

Comment: @Pawka добавил код в тело поста.

Comment: не знаю у меня все работает. Попробуй расставить print() и понятия, где код перестает работать или пройдись дебагером.

Answer (score 1):

В функции inline() переменная uid получает id сообщения, а не пользователя, как мне требовалось. Правильно надо было присваивать таким образом:

```
uid = c.from_user.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможен вариант использования message.chat.id, т.к. это и будет id юзера в данном случае.

```
uid = с.message.chat.id
```